# "Limited Access" permission de-selection

Tags: permissions, sharepoint

How do I de-select the "Limited Access" permission in SharePoint when it's not editable?

When I create a new user or new group the "Limited Access" permission is already selected and cannot be modified.  Is there a way to uncheck it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post about [Limited Access and how to remove it](http://tomresing.com/2010/07/12/what-is-limited-access-and-how-do-i-remove-it/).

The punch line is :

> To remove limited access, restore inheritance or remove the higher level permission given to the item or items.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you don't have to delete the Limited Access itself because it only shows you that some other levels of access are assigned to this user somewhere inside this container (site/web/list/folder) in another container that does not inherit permissions from its parent.